# How to add Azure Authentication to my current web application which is using API as well?

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

So my project has got a two asp.net projects. One is for showing date(User Interface) and the another one is API(for background processes like login, database calls and etc.). Right now my app has **Username** and **Password** feature to login. I have setup a startup class in my API which authenticates the user and pass the user token. Now I want to add a feature to login through **Azure portal**.
Can anyone suggest me a good practice in this situation? Like I don't want to change my code and just add a feature. Should I make changes in API or Web or Both? Meanwhile I was reading about **expose api** in app registration. Will it be appropriate to use it just for login purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD supports OAuth2, OIDC and SAML. See more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/index-web-app). It is probably best to introduce the mechanism through the API first, since it would apply to the frontend as well (though slight modifications may be required there as well).